# Ng-messages from inside template on components not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add ng-messages inside a template on a component, but the ng-message[s] nodes never get active after they get replaced by comments in angular, although the validation appropriately marks the md-input-container with the right classes

```
md-icon-float md-input-has-value md-input-invalid
```

Then, as the nodes never get activated, there is an error thrown:

```
mdInput messages show animation called on invalid messages element:
```

This works correctly if outside the component as the code below shows:

### HTML

```
<md-content id="content" layout="column" flex ng-app="app" >
    <md-content flex layout="column" layout-align="center center" layout-
    padding>

    <div layout="row" ng-form="demoForm">
        <picker> </picker>
        <div>
        <h2 class="md-subhead">HTML</h2>
          <mdp-time-picker name="timeFormat" ng-model="currentTimeText" mdp-
           format="HH:mm A">
            <div ng-messages="demoForm.timeFormat.$error">
              <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
              <div ng-message="format">Invalid format</div>
            </div>
          </mdp-time-picker>
        </div>
     </div>
     </md-content>
 </md-content>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#content { height: 100%; }
```

### JS

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module("app", [
    "ngMaterial",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngAria",   
    "ngMessages",
    "mdPickers"]); 

module.component('picker',
               {

     template: `
     <div>
          <h2 class="md-subhead">Component</h2>
          <mdp-time-picker name="timeFormat2" ng-model="currentTimeText" 
             mdp-format="HH:mm A">
             <div ng-messages="demoForm.timeFormat2.$error">
             <div ng-message="format">Invalid format</div>                   
            </div>
          </mdp-time-picker>
        </div>`,
     controller: "MainCtrl"
});


module.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$mdpDatePicker', 
'$mdpTimePicker', function($scope, $mdpDatePicker, $mdpTimePicker){

}]);
})();
```

A code pen with a working version  @ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwrXqg.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: disable auto-hiding. `md-auto-hide="false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `demoForm` inside your component because it has its own isolated scope (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition)

Just change your component template to use it's own form controller (or pass its reference through bindings)

```
module.component('picker',
   {
     template: `
        <div ng-form="pickerForm">
          <h2 class="md-subhead">Component</h2>
          <mdp-time-picker name="timeFormat2" ng-model="currentTimeText" 
             mdp-format="HH:mm A">
             <div ng-messages="pickerForm.timeFormat.$error">
                <div ng-message="format">Invalid format</div>                   
             </div>
          </mdp-time-picker>
        </div>`,
     controller: "MainCtrl"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working when I used a directive vs component.

```
  module.directive('picker', function() {
     return {
        template: `
        <div>
          <h2 class="md-subhead">Component</h2>
          <mdp-time-picker name="timeFormat2" ng-model="currentTimeText" mdp-format="HH:mm A">
            <div ng-messages="demoForm.timeFormat2.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
             <div ng-message="format">Invalid format</div>                   
            </div>
          </mdp-time-picker>
        </div>
        `,
        controller: "MainCtrl" // not sure you need this
};
```

}

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXjWjb

See also:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition

You'll probably need to work out how to pass through the element/form name and model value, too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to the comparison. This should work for components as well though; my guess is that components do not compile as directive do, but I am not pretty sure. For what I see directives are more powerful than components, however, components should also handle this case nicely as there is no evident reason why it should fail looking at the specification.

Comment: The only advantage (in my opinion) of directive over components is that you can use them as an attribute. Otherwise you should be using components which are easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @JesusNuñez . I'm keen to see the final solution to this and how you pass the model to the component.